# Определение модели iPhone под win

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Как различить между собой модели iPhone при подключении по USB к компьютеру?Я использовал для этих целей libusb и SetupAPI, с помощью этих либ я могу определить vendorID и productID, но проблема в том, что для разных моделей (я тестил для 5, 6s,6s+,7) и для этих моделей эти данные одинаковые. Я могу определить, что это подключен к компу iPhone, но какая именно модель не могу. Причем даже сама винда не всегда определяет точно модель, а вот айтюнс под виндой всегда точно определяет.

Comment: Как подсказывает капитан Очевидность, нужно взять какой-нибудь API-шпион (можно использовать даже WinDbg для этой цели) и посмотреть какие API вызываются в iTunes при подключении устройства. Хотя наверняка окажется, что данные считываются с какого-то текстового файла некой ПФС.